# Broken null checking for Optionals?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-java-interop

I've encountered a situation where Kotlin's nullable type checking is doing the opposite of what I'd expect. Have I misunderstood something fundamental, or is the following not expected behavior?

The return of getOrNull for an Optional of a non-nullable type can be checked for null without the compiler complaining.

```kotlin
class Compiles_TypeNonNullable {
    fun foo(o : Optional<String>): String {
        val result = o.getOrNull() ?: "fallback"
        return result
    }
}
```

While trying to add a null check when the Optional is for a nullable type results in a compile error.

```kotlin
class DoesNotCompile_TypeNullable {
    fun foo(o : Optional<String?>): String {
        val result = o.getOrNull() ?: "fallback"
        return result
    }
}
```

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
[ERROR] public fun <T : Any> Optional<TypeVariable(T)>.getOrNull(): TypeVariable(T)? defined in kotlin.jvm.optionals
```

This is the precise opposite of what I'd expect.

The above was observed with both Kotlin 1.9.10 and 1.9.23.

Comment: You expect the opposite of "The contents of an Optional containing a non-nullable type can be checked for null without the compiler complaining"? So you think you should *not* be able to check if `Optional<String>` is empty?

Comment: is it a `java.util.Optional`? If so, these cannot have a `null` element. `Optional<String?>` makes no sense.

Comment: @dan1stiscrying getOrNull returns null if the Optional is empty. My question is however badly phrased as it is talking about the contents of the Optional, which is not quite correct.

Comment: In your question, you have a `Optional<String?>` which does not make any sense. What do you want to achieve with that? The wrapped type of a `java.util.Optional` **cannot** be `null`.

Comment: @Sweeper If the nullabiliy of the wrapped type is going to affect compilation, I would expect it to compile in the situation that is possible and not compile in the situation that is not possible.

Comment: @dan1stiscrying an `Optional` can have null values. There's a static function `Optional.ofNullable(T value)` exactly for that

Comment: @dan1stiscrying Not my code. I just analyse it.

Comment: @Ivo That is an empty `Optional`, not an `Optional` with a `null` value.

Comment: @dan1stiscrying you're right. My mistake. I'm not that familiar with them so I was just now looking at it and overlooked that fact

Comment: Why is `Optional<String>` a "situation that is not possible"? As dan1st says, `Optional<String?>` is the impossible situation. An `Optional` cannot contain a null string.

Comment: @Sweeper you are correct that an Optional cannot contain null, but getOrNull will return null regardless of whether the type is nullable if the optional is empty.

So, perhaps not the opposite behaviour of what I'd expect, but certainly confusing.

Comment: Having now considered the other side of this, this does make sense since it is impossible (or at least not easy) to construct an a optional of a nullable type. Thank you everyone.

Comment: May be worth underlining that it's not usual to use Optional in Kotlin, as Kotlin's nullable types cover almost all the reasons for it, in a much more elegant, concise, and safe way.  (You may still need it for interoperability with Java code, of course.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getOrNull` only works on `Optional<T>`s where `T` is non-nullable. This is clear in it's declaration:

```
public fun <T : Any> Optional<T>.getOrNull(): T? = orElse(null)
```

The `: Any` constraint disallows any nullable types for `T`. `: Any` isn't technically needed here. The declaration still compiles without it, and it will return the wrapped non-null value or null if the optional is empty. But in Kotlin, `Optional<T?>` just doesn't make sense. The type constraint not only makes the intended usage clear, it also discourage people from using `Optional<T?>`.

Here is why `Optional<String?>` doesn't make sense.

An `Optional<T>` either:

- contains an instance of `T`, or;
- is empty

This makes sense for `Optional<String>` - it either contains a string or is empty. `getOrNull` returns the string if it is not empty, and returns null otherwise.

According to the same logic, an `Optional<String?>` in Kotlin can be any of the following:

- contains a string
- contains null
- is empty

The thing is, `Optional` cannot represent that second case. Internally, there is just a field of type `T`. If this field is null, the optional is empty, otherwise the optional contains an instance of `T`. `Optional` by design cannot distinguish between the second and third cases.

To represent all 3 cases, you would need a `Optional<Optional<String>>` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

In your **first** example, the Optional can be in any of these two states:

1. Contains a String
2. Is empty (as in "missing" as one would expect for something that's optional)

Now, `getOrNull` works as expected: It returns the String in the first case and it returns `null` in the second.

In your **second** example, the Optional can be in any of these three states:

1. Contains a `String`
2. Is empty
3. Contains `null`

That's what Kotlin sees, anyways. Since `Optional` is a Java type and Java's type system doesn't differentiate between nullable and non-nullable types, the second and the third cases are the same for Java, because internally, the Optional uses `null` to represent a missing value (case 2).

For Kotlin to correctly handle the last two cases, it would need to differentiate between them. Since that's not possible (the information just doesn't exist), it refuses to execute `getOrNull` at all. That is done by declaring that function to just work for non-nullable types:

```
public fun <T : Any> Optional<T>.getOrNull(): T?
```

`T` is of type `Any`, not of type `Any?`. That's why your second example won't compile, it is by design. And with good reason.

If you, as a developer, decide that to differentiate between cases two and three isn't important, you can always use this instead:

```
val result = o.orElse(null) ?: "fallback"
```

Edit: From the comments to the question it seems unlikely that you can construct an Optional with a nullable Kotlin type anyways. So all of this may be a moot point after all. You can *delcare* an `Optional<String?>`, but you'll only ever see a concrete object of the subtype `Optional<String>`.

Comment: In fact the Optional cannot contain null in the second example. This was the root of the error in my thinking. When an Optional is constructed it is always of a non-nullable type.

Comment: Yeah, I was already adding the edit to my answer. :)